# Select a cell of a table created with javascript

Tags: html, jquery

I'm trying to write a QR code to an HTML table, which I use as my grid.

I want to create the 3 eyes of my QR Code in the corners, but when I try to focus on a specific cell with its coordinates, it doesn't work.

Why doesn't the

```
$('#qrCodeGrid tr:eq(3) >td:eq(3)').css('background-color', 'black');
```

instruction turn the table cell black?

```js
var qrCodeSize = 21;
qrCodeSize++;

var table = '<table id="qrCodeGrid">';
for (let y = 1; y < qrCodeSize; y++) {
  table += '<tr data-y="' + y + '">';
  for (let x = 1; x < qrCodeSize; x++) {
    table += '<td data-x="' + x + '" data-y="' + y + '"></td>';
  }
  table += '</tr>';
}
$("body").append(table);

var eyeCoord = [[1, 1], [1, qrCodeSize - 7], [qrCodeSize - 7, 1]];

eyeCoord.forEach(element => {
  console.log(element[1]);
  $('#table tr:eq(3) >td:eq(3)').css('background-color', 'black');
});

$('#qrCodeGrid tr:eq(3) >td:eq(3)').css('background-color', 'black');
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid #efefef;
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have not changed your code, only turned it into an interactive snippet. The table cell is turning black. What are you asking about?

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it to work, if this is what you mean. Some points of attention:

- Why do you add 1 to `qrCodeSize` on line 2? If you want it to be 22, you can just declare it that way.
- You were using `#table` to select your table cells, while you should have used `#qrCodeGrid`.
- You were not dynamically selecting cells, I used string templates (with backticks and `${}` to do so.
- Please note the grid coordinates are zero-indexed when using `:eq()`.
- To ensure the DOM is fully loaded before coloring cells, use the document-ready shorthand `$( function() { ... })` in jQuery (see [documentation](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/))

```js
var qrCodeSize = 21;
qrCodeSize++; // Is this necessary? 

var table = '<table id="qrCodeGrid">';
for (let y = 1; y < qrCodeSize; y++) {
    table += '<tr data-y="' + y + '">';
    for (let x = 1; x < qrCodeSize; x++) {
        table += '<td data-x="' + x + '" data-y="' + y + '"></td>';
    }
    table += '</tr>';
}
$("body").append(table);

var eyeCoord = [[1, 1], [1, qrCodeSize - 7], [qrCodeSize - 7, 1]];

$(function() {
  eyeCoord.forEach(element => {
    $(`#qrCodeGrid tr:eq(${element[0]}) >td:eq(${element[1]})`).css('background-color', 'black');
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid #efefef;
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```